# Unable to understand which Java SDK to use when developing AWS Lambda Function

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When I was following the tutorial on deploying an AWS Lambda Function, I saw in it's sample that it uses an AWS Java SDK containing the interface Speechlet.

Here's a screenshot of the sample:

[image]

And the official documentation also states that I should use the Speechlet interface here: https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/handling-requests-sent-by-alexa

But unfortunately, when I installed the AWS Toolkit for Eclipse, there is no such interface in its toolkit. I also downloaded the AWS Java SDK from its official site but no Speechlet interface could be found.

And so, I searched again for some tutorials on how to create a Lambda Function using java then I came up with this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-eclipse/v1/user-guide/lambda-tutorial.html

This tutorial uses the Java SDK with no Speechlet interface! This really confuses me, because in its other documentation it states there clearly that it has a Speechlet interface and now it doesn't. I don't know how to continue this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum functionality your AWS Lambda function needs to support in Java is to have a class that implements a method with the following signature:

```
outputType handler-name(inputType input) {
   ...
}
```

If your signature looks something like this, no third-party libraries are necessary. You could have a Lambda handler that looks like this and it would work fine.

```
package LambdaExample;

public class Hello {
    public String lambdaHandler(String name) {
        return String.format("Hello %s!", name);
    }
}
```

In non-trivial usage, you'll likely see handler signatures that look something more like this:

```
outputType handler-name(inputType input, Context context) {
   ...
}
```

The [`Context` object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-context-object.html) can be used to retrieve information about your Lambda handler, as well as a logger you can use to log information about your handler to Cloudwatch.

The `Context` type is defined in `com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context`, which is provided by [`aws-lambda-java-core`](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs), part of a set of libraries that AWS publish for working with Lambda using Java/JVM languages. `aws-lambda-java-core` is separate from the AWS SDK for Java.

What you're running into seems to be a case of using very specific resources. Your image shows code for building a custom Alexa skill and deploying it to Lambda. If you are building an Alexa skill, then you will need to also include the [`alexa-skills-kit SDK`](https://github.com/amzn/alexa-skills-kit-java), which is what provides the `Speechlet` interface you see. The Alexa Skills Kit SDK is also separate from the AWS SDK for Java.

Assuming your project uses Maven for project management/dependencies, adding the following to the `<dependencies>` section should enable you to work with Lambda and Alexa:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazon.alexa</groupId>
  <artifactId>alexa-skills-kit</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer +1 for that. I have a copy of this skills kit SDK. However,  There seems to be no Jar file for me to import. I tried just copy pasting the entire source code from the the skills kit SDK and there are a bunch of errors on the imports, some of the imports are not found locally. I am using Eclipse to build the lambda function for Alexa skills, do you know how I can include the skills SDK into my project correctly?

Comment: @finalstatic are you using any sort of dependency/project manager for your project, or are you just copying source code from websites? If you're not using something like Gradle or Maven, I'd suggest looking into those so that you can specify dependencies like the Alexa SDK. My last bit in my post is a dependency list suitable for use with maven.

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much!